# JavaFX new message notification pop up

Tags: javafx

i am able to show popup, but its not replace another popup after closing a popup.after closing of popup this position will be replace by its previous one.how can i bring down the remain popups. here my code and image .

my notification method thats called when a new message come.
please help me out.`my global variables

```
private int n = 0;
```

public void notification(final JSONObject data, final String ip) throws JSONException {

```
    final Stage stage_notification = new Stage();
    stage_notification.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
    stage_notification.setWidth(250);
    stage_notification.setHeight(70);
    Dimension scrnSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    java.awt.Rectangle winSize = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getMaximumWindowBounds();

    int y = (int) (scrnSize.height - (scrnSize.height - winSize.height) - (stage_notification.getHeight() * (n + 1))); //increase popup one by one by adding 1
    int x = (int) ((scrnSize.width - stage_notification.getWidth()));

    stage_notification.setX(x);
    stage_notification.setY(y);
    n++;



    view_close.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent t) {
            t.consume();
            stage_notification.close();
            n--;
        }
    });


    final Timeline timeline = new Timeline();
    timeline.getKeyFrames().add(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(3),
            new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

                @Override
                public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                    stage_notification.close();
                    n--;
                }
            }));
    timeline.play();
```

}

```
![enter code here][1]
```